# How to target child elements within another wrapper

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors, parent

I currently have an issue targeting the right element within CSS. I want the .sizewave to target both itself and the one called .bp_bar  .  How can i solve the second one?

```
HTML:

<div class="bp_outer_wrapper">
    <img class="sizewave" src="media/images/heart.svg">
    <div class="bp_wrapper">
        <div class="bp_bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>


CSS:

/*This one works*/

.bp_outer_wrapper .sizewave:hover{
  animation: sizewave 1s 7 ease-in-out both;
}

/*This one does not work*/

.bp_outer_wrapper .sizewave:hover .bp_outer_wrapper .bp_wrapper      .bp_bar{
  animation: bloodpreassure 7s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do.

```
.sizewave + .bp_wrapper > .bp_bar {
  //CSS Styles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one the sibling selectors

[The general sibling selector ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
.bp_outer_wrapper .sizewave:hover ~ .bp_wrapper .bp_bar{
  animation: bloodpreassure 7s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

[The adjacent sibling selector +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
.bp_outer_wrapper .sizewave:hover + .bp_wrapper .bp_bar{
  animation: bloodpreassure 7s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next sibling elemnt + slector  see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
.bp_outer_wrapper .sizewave:hover + .bp_wrapper  .bp_bar{
  animation: bloodpreassure 7s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```